# In Azure logic app how to call rest api and get XML data and convert to json, when rest invocation for logic app is done

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am new to Logic apps previously i was using WSO2 ESB.In Azure logic app how to call rest api and get XML data and convert it to json. These all process has to start when logic app deployed in the form of rest api is invoked.

Comment: Did you manage to get this done? if yes can you let me know how did you get the XML Data from API in Logicapps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make Azure logic app work when it is invoked(like a rest API) first use request trigger. To convert XML to JSON use json() function and to convert JSON to XML use xml(). Both json() and xml() function are called expression.